# Mistake in iterate, Haskell

Tags: haskell

My program, where `n = 4`:

```
f n = take n (iterate (1+) 1)

main = do
    n <- getLine
    print(f (product(map read $ words n :: [Int])))
```

if `f n = take n (iterate (1+) 1)`  my answer is `[1,2,3,4]`. If each element in list divides on 4 answer is `[4, 2, 1.3333333333, 1]`.

I modify code `f n = take n (iterate (\x->(4/(x+1))) 1)` but now my answer is wrong: it's `[1.0,2.0,1.3333333333333333,1.7142857142857144]`, not `[4, 2, 1.3333333333, 1]`.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Why would it be `[4, 2, 1.3333333333, 1]`?

Comment: [1,2,3,4] => 4/1, 4/2, 4/3, 4/4

Comment: Uhm, `f n = [1..n]`. Also learn how to use `$` and `.`, we're not writing Lisp here.

Comment: @pertpoert: obviously, but why would it be `[4/1, 4/2, 4/3, 4/4]`?

Comment: @leftaroundabout `f n = take n (iterate (\x->(4/(x+1))) 1)`

Comment: `f n = map (4/) [1..n]` ?

Comment: Look closely at what `iterate` does. You need to map a `[1..n]` list, no need to use `iterate`.

Comment: @pertpoert Are you sure you wouldn't instead want `map (\x -> 4 / (x + 1)) [1..]` instead?  `iterate` uses the last result as input to the function and repeatedly applies it.  `take 5 $ iterate (+1) 1 == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define f as

```
   f :: Int -> Double
   f n = sum $ map (4/) $ map fromIntegral [1..n]
```

you have to watch for mixing numerical types in computations.  Now your function should work

```
> f $ product (map read $ words "23 4 32" :: [Int])
34.259639888367765
```

Comment: that will be a different function.  However, it's the same issue: mixing different numerical types.  You have to change it to `f n = sum $ map (fromIntegral n/) $ map fromIntegral [1..n]`

Answer (score 0):

Try writing it in C:

```
f n = take n $ iterate (1+) 1
```

translates to

```
void
f(int n) {
    int i;
    double t = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%g\n", t);
        t = 1 + t;
    }
}
```

So

```
f n = take n (iterate (\x->(4/(x+1))) 1)
```

translates to

```
void
f(int n) {
    int i;
    double t = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%g\n", t);
        t = 4 / (t + 1);
    }
}
```

which has the same effect.  You're doing the division `(4 /)` in between the `(1 +)` additions, which is why you're getting the wrong answer.  In C, you put `4 / t` in the output and `1 + t` when updating the temporary:

```
void
f(int n) {
    int i;
    double t = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%g\n", t / 4);
        t = t + 1;
    }
}
```

and the Haskell equivalent of that is using two list functions:

```
f n = take n $ map (4/) $ iterate (1+) 1
```